# How do i change a DropdownMenuItem in Flutter? (Failed assertion)

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to build a Dropdown Menu with Recent used Colors from my Colorpicker. Therefore i got a List with DropdownMenuItems:

```
static Color recentUsedColor1;
...(5 of them)
List<DropdownMenuItem<Color>> recentUsedColors = [
    DropdownMenuItem(
      child: Container(height: 20,width: 20,color: recentUsedColor1,),
      value: recentUsedColor1,
    ),
    ...(5 of them) ];
```

and a DropdownButton in my Build Method:

``

```
DropdownButton(
                value: recentUsedColor1,
                items: recentUsedColors,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    brushColor = value;
                  });
                },
              ),``
```

Now if a new color gets selected i put the old one on the recentUsedColor1 variable:

```
``ColorPicker(
    color: Colors.blue,
    onChanged: (value) {
    setState(() {
      recentUsedColor1 = brushColor;
      brushColor = value;
                                      });
                                    })
```

``

but somehow i get the Error in the Moment i select a new color in my colorpicker ( in the moment i try to change the variable recentUsedColor1) and i dont understand why.

Detailed Error:

```
I/flutter ( 3095): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

The following assertion was thrown building Grid(dirty, dependencies: [MediaQuery, LocalizationsScope-[GlobalKey#0922e], _InheritedTheme], state: GridState#ea90e):

'package:flutter/src/material/dropdown.dart': Failed assertion: line 620 pos 15: 'items == null ||
items.isEmpty || value == null || items.where((DropdownMenuItem<T> item) => item.value ==
value).length == 1': is not true.
```

Comment: I tried it in the release version now, and there i do not get the error. But instead the  value of my DropDownButton gets empty if i select a color with the colorpicker. And if i reload the page after, then all recentUsedColors are the last used color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error means recentUsedColors is not init or empty

```
items: recentUsedColors,
```

Not sure what color picker you use. but concept is the same 
Use `List<Color>` to record history color and generate DropdownButton

code snippet

```
DropdownButton<Color>(
                    //isDense: true,
                    hint: Text('Choose a goal category'),
                    value: dropdownValue,
                    icon: Icon(Icons.check_circle_outline),
                    iconSize: 24,
                    elevation: 16,
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.deepPurple),
                    underline: Container(
                      height: 2,
                      color: Colors.blue[300],
                    ),
                    onChanged: (Color newValue) {
                      setState(() {
                        dropdownValue = newValue;
                      });
                    },
                    items: recentUsedColors
                        .map<DropdownMenuItem<Color>>((Color value) {
                      return DropdownMenuItem<Color>(
                        value: value,
                        child: Container(height: 20, width: 20, color: value),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                  ),
```

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:flutter_colorpicker/flutter_colorpicker.dart';
import 'package:flutter_colorpicker/material_picker.dart';
import 'package:flutter_colorpicker/block_picker.dart';
import 'package:flutter_colorpicker/utils.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  Color currentColor = Colors.amber;

  List<Color> recentUsedColors = [];
  Color dropdownValue;

  void changeColor(Color color) {

    setState(() {
      currentColor = color;
      recentUsedColors.add(color);
    });

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 3,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Flutter Color Picker Example'),
          bottom: TabBar(
            tabs: <Widget>[
              const Tab(text: 'HSV'),
              const Tab(text: 'Material'),
              const Tab(text: 'Block'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          children: <Widget>[
            Center(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  DropdownButton<Color>(
                    //isDense: true,
                    hint: Text('Choose a goal category'),
                    value: dropdownValue,
                    icon: Icon(Icons.check_circle_outline),
                    iconSize: 24,
                    elevation: 16,
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.deepPurple),
                    underline: Container(
                      height: 2,
                      color: Colors.blue[300],
                    ),
                    onChanged: (Color newValue) {
                      setState(() {
                        dropdownValue = newValue;
                      });
                    },
                    items: recentUsedColors
                        .map<DropdownMenuItem<Color>>((Color value) {
                      return DropdownMenuItem<Color>(
                        value: value,
                        child: Container(height: 20, width: 20, color: value),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                  ),
                  RaisedButton(
                    elevation: 3.0,
                    onPressed: () {
                      showDialog(
                        context: context,
                        builder: (BuildContext context) {
                          return AlertDialog(
                            titlePadding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                            contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                            content: SingleChildScrollView(
                              child: ColorPicker(
                                pickerColor: currentColor,
                                onColorChanged: changeColor,
                                colorPickerWidth: 300.0,
                                pickerAreaHeightPercent: 0.7,
                                enableAlpha: true,
                                displayThumbColor: true,
                                enableLabel: true,
                                paletteType: PaletteType.hsv,
                                pickerAreaBorderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                                  topLeft: const Radius.circular(2.0),
                                  topRight: const Radius.circular(2.0),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      );
                    },
                    child: const Text('Change me'),
                    color: currentColor,
                    textColor: useWhiteForeground(currentColor)
                        ? const Color(0xffffffff)
                        : const Color(0xff000000),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Center(
              child: RaisedButton(
                elevation: 3.0,
                onPressed: () {
                  showDialog(
                    context: context,
                    builder: (BuildContext context) {
                      return AlertDialog(
                        titlePadding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                        contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                        content: SingleChildScrollView(
                          child: MaterialPicker(
                            pickerColor: currentColor,
                            onColorChanged: changeColor,
                            enableLabel: true,
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  );
                },
                child: const Text('Change me'),
                color: currentColor,
                textColor: useWhiteForeground(currentColor)
                    ? const Color(0xffffffff)
                    : const Color(0xff000000),
              ),
            ),
            Center(
              child: RaisedButton(
                elevation: 3.0,
                onPressed: () {
                  showDialog(
                    context: context,
                    builder: (BuildContext context) {
                      return AlertDialog(
                        title: Text('Select a color'),
                        content: SingleChildScrollView(
                          child: BlockPicker(
                            pickerColor: currentColor,
                            onColorChanged: changeColor,
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  );
                },
                child: const Text('Change me'),
                color: currentColor,
                textColor: useWhiteForeground(currentColor)
                    ? const Color(0xffffffff)
                    : const Color(0xff000000),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

working demo

[image]